# A 4-digit flag count label overlaps the mod message field

Tags: bug, top-bar

Not a big deal, but let's add 3 more pixels to keep those two things separated? :)

[image: top bar for mods]

Comment: Work harder, then it won't overlap ;)

Comment: Maybe we're addressing the wrong problem here...

Comment: Why not simply show `1k`, `1.2k` similar to the number display in other places?

Comment: @AsheeshR: Probably for the same reason your exact rep is displayed in the top bar and your profile versus its abbreviation everywhere else.

Comment: @Nick you can show "1K", right? ;)

Comment: My point (not clearly stated) was that `>1k` flags is (should be?) an edge case. My guess is only SO can reach that number frequently, so rounding off (as is in the case for other huge numbers on the site) wouldn't affect usability in any way and wouldn't break the design.

Answer (score 5):

Not a big deal, but I think we can all agree that it would be a better idea to subtract 4 digits from the flag count label.

Comment: Or the entire label, if you prefer.